Constructing subgroup comparisons for variable selection
I am trying to construct a covariate according to the the following description:

When constructing the covariates to measure a subgroup effect, we
generate covariates that capture the causal effect of a given variable
in a given subgroup. The covariates are constructed such that, within
each subgroup, the treatment group and control group are contrasted;
outside the subgroup, the covariate is set to zero.
This covariate is constructed such that the coefficient from
regressing the outcome on this covariate gives the difference in means
in that subgroup. It does so by zeroing out observations of the
subgroup, but creating a contrast between the treated and controls in
that subgroup. Note that this covariate could be constructed instead
to contrast those in treatment condition k to some other condition.
This covariate treats all of the treatment levels except for k as the
baseline, so coefficients on this covariate should be interpreted as
the mean difference between the given treatment and the average of all
other treatment levels for this variable.

Ratkovic, M. (2021). Subgroup Analysis: Pitfalls, Promise and Honesty. In J. N. Druckman & D. P. Green (Eds.), Advances in experimental political science (pp. 271–288). Cambridge University Press.
I am not sure how to construct these subgroup covariates. The point of these covariates is to include many of them in a lasso model to select the most important ones. Since we are interested in finding heterogeneity in the treatment effect, the covariates should represent the difference in means between treatment and control within the subgroup (or a sum contrast difference as described in the last sentences). If the covariates or interactions meant something else, you would regularize the wrong effects.
How should these covariates be coded? I was thinking maybe to code the within-subgroup control as -0.5, the within-subgroup treatment as 0.5, and everything else outside the subgroup as 0. But you would still have to exclude a category in the lasso model, right?
Am I right that the simple treatment x subgroup method won't do?

This approach seems to far away from rigorous and simpler interaction specification, and it doesn’t work for continuous covariates.

I see, thank you for your answer! What part especially do you find to be far away from rigorous? I did not reproduce the whole description of the process from the chapter here, just that one specific part about the covariates.
It is definitely meant to only work with subgroup categories.

To flip that, what part of it do you deem particularly rigorous and respectful of statistical principles?

I don’t really know what part is bothering you. Contrast coding in this manner doesn’t seem particularly divisive to me (of course you would still include main effects). If you are interested in the specifics of their application of the lasso, I can only refer you to their treatment and to the statistical literature they are citing. But I could be misrepresenting something that is triggering to you specifically, please tell me. English is not my first language.

I’m reacting mainly to (1) your need to mention the word ‘subgroup’ instead of just directly formulating the contrast of interest and (2) the fact that the approach only works for truly discrete covariates unless I’ve missed something.  The term ‘subgroup analysis’ implies a naive data subsetting analysis that messes up the covariate adjustment and uses a poor estimate of residual variance when using a linear model.

I see, that makes sense. It is used here in the sense of treatment effect heterogeneity. In fact, the author (and the literature they draw from) are trying to teach practitioners about the dangers of fishing for statistically significant interaction terms. Instead, they propose a sample splitting aproach combined with p-value adjustment.
I am in fact struggling with formulating the contrast of interest. That is what my (confusing) question was meant to be.
The categorizing of continuous data is absolutely a huge downside compared to similar ideas like regression trees (Athey and others).

That approach has a lot of problems.  Far better: penalize all the interaction terms and don’t waste sample size by splitting.  More here.

Thank you, that seems like a good alternative.
